# In html how do I have table within table look visually the same as if I didnt have the inner table

Tags: html, css

What do I set to table style so that if I have multiple tables one level within the table (i.e  that the inner table is not shifted to the right and down.

In the original picture there is just one table, this is how I want things to look

[image: Original With One table]

In the second screenshot I now have an outer table and three tables within it, I tried setting the style of the outer table to **border-collapse** to remove the vertical gaps between tables and the shift to the right of all three tables but it hasn't worked as I imagined it has just remove the lines between table cells within the tables. (table width is also set to 100%)

How can I have the tables within outer table but looking like the first screenshot. (I need the tables within table because Im writing a javascript method to allow the inner table to be hidden).
In the second screenshot there is one outer table
[image: Table within table]

So the html is like this:

```
<table class="releasegroupingtable" >
<!--Linked-->
<tr><td><table class="releasegroupingcategory" >
......
</table></td></tr>

<!--Not Linked-->
<tr><td><table class="releasegroupingcategory" >
......
</table></td></tr>

<!--Discogs-->
<tr><td><table class="releasegroupingcategory" >
......
</table></td></tr>
</table>
```

and the css like this:

```
.releasegroupingtable {
    width:100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.releasegroupingcategory {
    width:100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Comment: It's most likely a `margin`, `padding` or `border-spacing`, but there's not telling without looking at your code. Mind providing the relevant bits?

Comment: @Siguza ok done, as you can see there is very little formatting currently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code you provided, it looks like there is some padding on `td`s in the outer table.
You should be able to fix it by adding

```
.releasegroupingtable > tbody > tr > td
{
    padding: 0;
}
```

The selector chain is necessary to not select `td`s in `.releasegroupingcategory` too.

Comment: Ah yes sorry you are right (not sure why) but in my css I have  td  {padding: 5px;}, okay fixed.